# React Native FlatList Error -- "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): undefined is not an object"

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, axios

Okay, here's the situation:

I'm working on a React Native app using Redux, and I want to display the results of a GET request (made using Axios) using a FlatList. However, when I try to render that data using a FlatList, I get an error, and nothing at all is displayed! I'm sure that data is being returned, because I can display it using normal Text components, but I need to be able to put it all into a FlatList.

Totally flummoxed by the following error:
[screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KRgm.png)

The action I'm dispatching to make the call is as follows (I'm using promise middleware):

```
{
  type: 'PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE',
  payload: axios.get(base + '/proposals/get_recent?page=1'),
}
```

My reducer code is as follows:

```
const defaultState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  proposalList: [],
  error: null,
};

const proposalReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_PENDING":
      state = {...state, fetching: true, fetched: false};
      break;
    case "PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_FULFILLED":
      state = {...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, proposalList: action.payload.data.data.proposals};
      break;
    case "PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_REJECTED":
      state = {...state, fetching: false, fetched: false, error: action.payload.message};
      break;
    default: break;
  }
  return state;
}

export default proposalReducer;
```

Finally, the smart component I'm using to actually display all this:

```
import Proposal from './Proposal'

class ProposalFeed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    props.dispatch(fetchProposalPage(1));
  }

  render() {
    const proposals = this.props.proposal.proposalList.map(
      proposal => ({...proposal, key:proposal.id})
    );

    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={proposals}
          renderItem={({proposal}) => (<Proposal
            name={proposal.name}
            summary={proposal.summary}
          />)}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect((store) => {
  return {
    proposal: store.proposal,
  }
})(ProposalFeed);
```

And the dumb "Proposal" component!

```
import styles from './Styles';

class Proposal extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.horizontalContainer}>
        <View style={styles.verticalContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.name}>{this.props.name}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.summary}>{this.props.summary}</Text>
          <View style={styles.bottom}></View>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Proposal;
```

Any help would be HUGELY appreciated! I've been looking around for a solution to this for a while, and absolutely nothing has worked. I'm also worried the problem might be the middleware that I'm using (redux-promise-middleware), but I'm not sure.

Comment: It looks like it's trying to render before the data is returned...have you tried having a loading block with an ActivityIndicator, and setState accordingly once you've gotten your response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before

```
  <View>
    <FlatList
          data={proposals}
          renderItem={({proposal}) => (<Proposal
            name={proposal.name}
            summary={proposal.summary}
          />)}
        />
   </View>
```

After

```
<View>
   <FlatList
      data={proposals}
      renderItem={({item}) => (<Proposal
      name={item.name}
      summary={item.summary}
      />)}
    />
 </View>
```

replace `proposal` to `item`。 It seems that `FlatList` is forced to use the `item`
as `renderItem`'s object

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed my problem!

Comment: this damn bug waste 3 hours of my time , thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

Not good way to implement redux with API call, below is a way i follow to implement API call...

```
//Actions

export function fetchStart() {
 return  {
  type: 'PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_PENDING',
  }
}


export function fetchSuccess(data) {
 return  {
  type: 'PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_FULFILLED', 
  data
  }
}


export function fetchFailure(err) {
 return  {
  type: 'PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_REJECTED',
  err
  }
}

The below function is the main function that you need to digest in order to fetch data in a proper way.

export function fetchPage()
{
  return (dispatch) => {
   dispatch(fetchStart())
   axios.get(base + '/proposals/get_recent?page=1').
   then((response) =>  dispatch(fetchSuccess(response)))
   .catch((err) => { dispatch(fetchFailure(err)) })
  }
} 

//reducer

const defaultState = {
  fetching: false,
  fetched: false,
  proposalList: [],
  error: null,
};

const proposalReducer = (state=defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_PENDING":
      state = {...state, fetching: true, fetched: false};
      break;
    case "PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_FULFILLED":
      state = {...state, fetching: false, fetched: true, proposalList: action.data.data.proposals};
      break;
    case "PROPOSALS_FETCH_PAGE_REJECTED":
      state = {...state, fetching: false, fetched: false, error: action.err.message};
      break;
    default: break;
  }
  return state;
}

//component
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //the main function is called here
    props.dispatch(fetchPage());
  }
```

Cheers :)

Comment: Do you mean that using redux-promise-middleware is a bad call? From what I understood of their documentation, it accomplishes the same thing as having three separate actions--but maybe I interpreted wrong! Thank you.

Comment: I would recommend you to use redux-thunk